# Teamcity can not find skd 8.1

Tags: c++, teamcity

Every time when I am trying to build solution I get error `error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'dxgi1_2.h': No such file or directory`.

It seems that build agent does not have Sdk 8.1. How to check it in TeamCity settings?

**Update**

In TeamCity I see

**Actual Parameters on Agent
Configuration Parameters**

WindowsSDKv8.1_Path    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1

In my project i Added to Additional Include Directories path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1". Still not working...